# Using Apache Beam in Python to create a template in GCP Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

**Task :**
I need to take data from Oracle on premise and dump it in BigQuery.

**Option which I tried**
There are various ways to achieve the same.

1. I tried first option i.e with Datastream but due to limitations at Database end .
2. I used python script to fetch the data from source database and it's working as of now. But I need to check another option i.e.dataflow  (serverless point of view)
   Flow would be like this
   a) Create a template in GCS bucket using Python
   b) Dataflow job will execute that template
   (It will establish connection string and dump the data in BigQuery)

**Current hurdles**
After searching thru' stuff, I could create a customized Python Template but it's source is Flat file
What code changes are required in Python (using Apache Beam) by which I can achieve the same using Oracle as a source ? Do we need to use only jdbc connectivity option ? I had gone thru' some Dataflow templates but did not get much information .

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/connectors/ for the built-in IOs. You could use the Python jdbc io via x-lang.